# How to download files from a repository using python

Tags: python, bitbucket

I am now practicing automation using selenium using python language.
I now want to to download the an archive file (database scripts) from bitbucket repository to my local machine.

- Is there any way to do it?
- Can you help me in giving some sample code to do the same?

Note: I'm using python 3.4. (I have a private repository)

Comment: You don't need selenium for this, just `git`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not code writing service. Please try yourself and come back if you have any problem with what you have tried.

Comment: I tried a lot.Now finally, I have cloned the repository using source tree.As a result I have the repository files that I wanted in a desired location of my local machine.But whenever there is a new update, i will have to do it manually by doing a 'pull' on the source tree.

Comment: I am now trying to update those scripts using python on my local machine.Thank you..